# How to assign list of variables to another list

Tags: dart

The end goal is to assign a list of Futures to a list of variables.

This is how I would accomplish this goal in node;

```
let name;
let number;

[name, number] = await Promise.all([promiseName(), promiseNumber()]);
```

I know that with Dart there is `await Future.wait([]);`, but I'm unsure how to go about assign the results to different variables instead of having the `List<Future>`  assigned to a single variable and then I go through that variable via index.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way in Dart to assign to more than one variable at a time.
You'll have to do:

```dart
String name;
int number;
var list = await Future.wait([asyncName(), asyncNumber()]);
name = list[0] as String;
number = list[1] as int;
```

if you use existing variables, or

```dart
var list = await Future.wait([asyncName(), asyncNumber()]);
var name = list[0] as String;
var number = list[1] as int;
```

if you can declare them after you have the results.